# .hbs syntax highlighting in Coda (OSX)

Tags: macos, handlebars.js, coda

Does anyone know how I can enable syntax highlighting for .hbs files in Coda?
At the moment everything is in white. If I rename the file to something.html it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this myself.

In Coda Preferences, Select Editor, add a Custom Syntax Mode at the bottom.